# How to send data to smart contract?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, calldata

I have the variable w1_temp, which i need to send to contract 
I have the following code:

```js
var W1Temp = require('w1temp')
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3()

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8042'))
var contractAddress = '0x414c49c9552c4bd41401ff0a67ff84431a900c66'
var ABI = JSON.parse(
'[ { "inputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ 
{ "name": "_sensorData", "type": "int256" } ], "name": "setSensorData", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": 
"nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getSensorData", "outputs": [ { "name": "", 
"type": "int256", "value": "0" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" } ] ')

var StoreIntegerValue = web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(contractAddress)

W1Temp.setGpioData(7)
W1Temp.getSensor('28-0316612396ff').then(function (sensor) {
    var _sensorData = sensor.getTemperature();
});

eth.sendTransaction({
    from: 'a57f7e5347bd04076dd02c02212c0221522289ff38940e', 
    to: '0x414c49c9552c4bd41401ff0a67ff84431a900c66',
    value: web3.toWei(100,'finney'),
    data: web3.toHex('_sensorData')
})
```

But I’m almost sure that it is not correct
Please help to make it work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the contract ABI you can create an instance pointing to contract's address and call methods directly.

```
var StoreIntegerValue=web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(contractAddress);

W1Temp.setGpioData(7)
W1Temp.getSensor('28-0316612396ff').then(function (sensor){
  var _sensorData = sensor.getTemperature();

  StoreIntegerValue.setSensorData(_sensorData, { 
    from: "0x123412341234.." 
  });
});
```

But you should ask the person who provided the ABI which methods are available, their parameters and requisites.

Comment: It still does not work, whenever I call the contract it returns the same data that I sent to execute it. As I understood the value sent into the contract can be anything. Here is my smart contract.  pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract StoreIntegerValue {
 address owner;
 int sensorData;

 function StoreIntegerValue() {
 owner = msg.sender;
 }

 function setSensorData(int _sensorData) {
 require(msg.sender == owner);
 sensorData = _sensorData;
 }

 function getSensorData() constant returns (int) {
 require(msg.sender == owner);
 return sensorData;
 }
}

Comment: I do not understand your issue. If you call setSensorData with a new value, after the transaction is mined it should return the new value when you call getSensorData. Perhaps the require is failing and causing the transaction to revert, for test just comment out the require sentences. Also try specifying the gas `{ from: "0x..", gas: 1000000 }`.

Comment: I do not call sensor data, it is written in read from contract field. Also when i send transaction, it says “It seems transaction will fail. If you submit it it may consume all the gas you provide”, and then lets me send the transaction.

Comment: And what is the require? How to find it? Is it artifacts?

Comment: In your contract code there's a `require(msg.sender == owner);` this causes that only the contract owner can send data to the contract.

Comment: Is the contract owner the one logged in Mist? I did not assign any owners to contract

Comment: The owner is the address that deployed the contract.

Comment: In mist I have two accounts from miner 1, coinbase and the other. Which of them is the owner?

Comment: Just to clarify, I have uploaded a picture of what I see in mist, so you could see. So, then I call setIntegerValue, I send a transaction of arbitrary number, and then it returns exacly same number, (in the picture my next attempt to make a transaction is shown), so should I send it from different account?or identify contract owner somewhere?

Comment: From your contract code you have to use the same account for deploying the contract and to send data to the contract. If you can edit your contract and remove the `require(msg.sender == owner)` then any address should be able to send data to your contract.