# Input from IOT devices direct to the smart contracts?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, dapp-development, iot

I went through almost all the answers on IOT but not got the answer.

I want to create a DAPP which takes temp as input from IOT device and trigger function in the smart contract.
I know the options like to take input in fronend and using web3js to direct it to Smart Contract and Cloud services like Azure. Other than these options.

What are the possible ways to achieve this scenario?
Any help is much appreciated.
--edit--
Other than Oraclize or chainlink.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create [Oracles](http://www.oraclize.it/) to get data from the sensors to the smart contract.

Oracles are trusted data feeds that send information into the Smart Contract, removing the need for Smart Contracts to directly access information outside their network, thus lightening their workload. Oracles are usually supplied by third parties and are authorized by the companies that use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping are there any other way otherthan oraclize or chainlink?

Comment: You will have to choose either centralized (Oracles) or decentralized Oracle(Chainlink). Otherwise, you need to enter input manually. I dont think there is any other possible way to feed sensor's data in smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to let your device push changes directly to a contract.

For example if you have a temperature sensor then every temperature change will be written to a contract on the blockchain.

If your dapp want to use the temperature it will read direclty from the sensor contract.

Comment: Can you please tell which solution you are referring? and about sensor contract how to give direct input in contract? Can you please explain or share the resource?

Comment: Something similar to this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45123/